# ¿Cómo convertir en un repositorio un subcarpeta del mismo repositorio?

Tags: git, github

Actualmente estoy realizando un despliegue automático del repositorio mediante webhooks y este se activa cuando el repositorio recibe un PUSH.

El detalle es que se lleva todo el repositorio, lo cual no necesito, solo necesito que se llevue una subcarpeta del repositorio.

El despliegue lo estoy haciendo mediante Plesk, quien solicita la dirección del proyecto ya sea del protocolo HTTPS o SSH.

En mi repositorio contiene las siguientes subcarpetas:

- Analisis
- Sitio Web   <--- Convertir a repositorio y tenga su propia ruta .git
- Plantilla

Al realizar el despligue solo necesito que se lleve la subcarpeta "Sitio Web", he leido que con submódulos podría solucionarse, pero no he logrado solucionarlo.

Nota: Existirá una solución para que "Sitio Web" realmente forme parte de mi repositorio original y no sea una referencia de otro repositorio? por que a lo que he leido eso hace submódulos.

Saludos y gracias.

Comment: En lugar de submódulos te interesará tratarlo como subárbol. Lee sobre ello [aqui](https://www.atlassian.com/blog/git/alternatives-to-git-submodule-git-subtree) o [aqui](https://blog.kaleidos.net/2018/07/31/Tutorial-git-subtree/)